# How to get Reacjs input text value without any form

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I have a newbie in Reactjs and it must be an easy question. I didn't find that. But it doesn't work. It might be asked already

```
class App extends Component {

constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        currency: '',
        excurrency: '',
        amount: ''
    }
}

<input id='amount' type='text' onChange={(amount) => this.setState({amount})}></input>
<button onClick={ () => alert('show me amount '+this.state.amount)}>amount</button>
}
```

After I give some input, I was expecting that it should set new value to amount. But when I click the button it shows alert as:- show me amount [object Object] 
Why it doesn't set new value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onClick callback gets event object as input/argument instead of text value. you need to get the value of input from that event object

```
<input id='amount' type='text' onChange={(e) => this.setState({ amount: e.target.value })}></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You data may have not updated before your alert fires. setState comes with a callback for just that thing.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value}, ()  => {
   console.log(this.state.amount)
}) 
}

<input name='amount' type='text' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
```